# Remove =?UTF-8?Q? from subject field in codeigniter mail to sms

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, sms

I am working in Codeigniter and sending an sms message by email and I am getting =?UTF-8?Q? and other tags in my sms subject line in certain conditions.  I would like to stop this.

OBSERVATIONS:
I have a variable that is built like this:

```
 $subject = 'Waiting List Update from Test Calendar';
```

This variable is sent to the subject field for email as such

```
 $this->email->subject($subject);
```

When sent with html, `$config['mailtype'] = 'html';` to standard email this works.  The subject reads:

```
 "Waiting List Update from Test Calendar"
```

When sent to SMS I am getting the following in my subject field:

```
 "Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Waiting=20List=20Update=20?==?UTF-8?Q?from=20Tes?= =?UTF-8?Q?t=20Calendar?"
```

But if I put the text into the subject field directly like this:

```
 $this->email->subject('Waiting List Update from Test Calendar');
```

The result is what is desired:

```
    "Subject: Waiting List Update from Test Calendar"
```

If I shorten the `$subject` to 20 characters the result produces:

```
 "Subject: Waiting List Update"
```

1. Why do I get the 20 character limit when placing the message in a variable but not when placed directly in quotes within the subject field?
2. How can I overcome this 20 character limit in variables and stop getting the UTF-8 tags?

Answer (score 1):

This happen in case your subject uses an icon char, so you can convert MIME-encoded text in subject to UTF-8.

```
imap_utf8($your_subject);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-expunge.php[Php Manual][1]